# Detailed proof of Central Limit Theorem for Markov Chains

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, markov-chains, markov-process

Can someone please provide a reference to a detailed proof of the CLT for MC? I have a paper [MC's for MCMC'ists](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1403908?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) but I have a problem understanding a crucial part. Namely, the transition from line 2 to line 3 here

[image]

So I am looking for a different source where this transition will be better explained. Does anybody know of a source with a detailed proof? I do not want a source, littered with "it can be shown" and "it follows from (something not in the text)...", but something I can learn from. The attached source is great, but I cannot understand the mentioned transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step that interests you is rather direct. To see why it holds, first rewrite the double sum in the expectation as $$S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(X_k) f(X_{k+m})\mathbf 1_{T>k+m}$$ then condition each $k$-term by $\sigma(X_k)$. This yields $$E(S)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty E\left(f(X_k) E\left( f(X_{k+m})\mathbf 1_{T>k+m}\mid X_k\right)\right)$$ By the Markov property and the homogeneity of the Markov chain, for each $k$ and each positive $m$, $$E\left( f(X_{k+m})\mathbf 1_{T>k+m}\mid X_k\right)=\mathbf 1_{T>k}g_m(X_k)$$ where $$g_m(x)=E\left(f(X_m)\mathbf 1_{T>m}\mid X_0=x\right)$$ This is the formula in your text, minus the typo $Y_0=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I understood correctly, but I would like to ask a follow-up if I may. Your parenthesis, in the second line, seem to brace around differently, than in the text. In the text, I interpreted them as if we have a product of two expectations. Second, what do you mean by condition on $\sigma(X_k)$? And the expectation in the innermost parenthesis, does that come from the total law of expectation?

Thank you very much. I am an amateur, and kind people like you on SE help me when  I get stuck.

Comment: ...As you were already explained [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2663877).

Comment: Yes. I applied the first step correctly. But failed to finish...

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain on the difference in parenthesis? Your solution has a nested expectation, while in the third line of the text, there seems to be a product. What am I missing? Sorry for all the questions...

Comment: My suggestion: concentrate on the approach in my answer, what would be unclear in it?